# Как правильно генерировать идентификатор для Redis

Tags: spring, spring-boot, redis

### Проблема

Если в JPA мы могли описать инкрементацию id поля сущности с помощью `@GeneratedValue`, то используя Redis нам не предоставляется возможности добавить обычную инкрементацию id из коробки, вместо этого генерируется строковый UUID на подобии такого 232c5383-9010-42dc-ab1a-c9094642a507.

### Решение

**Вариант 1**

В Redis выделить дополнительное поле. Когда добавляется новая запись в БД, то достается значение этого поля -> идентификатору объекта присваивается его значение -> инкрементация значения поля -> сохранение.

**Post**

```
@RedisHash(post)
public class Post

private long id;

public Post(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

// getters & setters
```

**Сервис**

```
public void add() {

    // Беру значение дополнительного поля из Redis
    long identifier = redisTemplate.opsForValue().get("identifier");

    // Запихиваю его в объект основным идентификатором
    postRepository.save(new Post(identifier));

    // Инкрементирую
    redisTemplate.opsForValue().set("identifier", ++identifier);

}
```

---

**Вариант 2**

Добавить объекту второй идентификатор в виде значения дополнительного поля.

**Post**

```
@RedisHash(post)
public class Post

    @Id
    private String id;

    private long identifier; // Кастомный инкрементный идентификатор

    public Post(long identifier) {
        this.identifier = identifier;
    }

    // getters & setters
```

**Сервис**

```
public void add() {

    // Беру значение дополнительного поля из Redis
    long identifier = redisTemplate.opsForValue().get("identifier");

    // Запихиваю его в объект вторым идентификатором
    postRepository.save(new Post(identifier));

    // Инкрементирую
    redisTemplate.opsForValue().set("identifier", ++identifier);

}
```

### Заключение

Приемлем ли такой способ генерации уникального id объекта или же есть варианты куда интересней? Хотелось бы узнать как вы справляетесь с данным вопросом.

Comment: Вам нужно именно число? У варианта 1 минус тот, что нужно будет синхронизировать создание идентификатора, т.е. нельзя будет параллельно вставлять несколько сущностей в redis. вариант 2 я не понял. Если нет особой необходимости, то используйте uuid

Comment: @RomanKonoval Да, мне нужен уникальный числовой идентификатор для быстрой фильтрации списка по id поста на фронте. Второй вариант переписал, добавил примеры кода. Получается что и во втором варианте тот же минус...

Comment: Значит буду синхронизировать.

Comment: У меня большие сомнения, что в веб приложении будет разница в скорости в этом сценарии в фильтрации, если будете использовать uuid вместо числа. А вот усложнение генерации ради числа - это проблема.

Comment: @RomanKonoval неправильно выразился: Для удобной фильтрации списка по id. Хочется чтобы пользователю не приходилось вбивать длинный айдишник, а обойтись коротким числовым идентификатором максимум из 8 цифр. Придумал еще вариант: на фронте динамически выводить найденные результаты по первым введенным символам. Скорее всего буду рассматривать такой способ, потому что синхронизация будет стопить запросы. Это как то через чур)

Comment: Вы пользователю предлагаете вручную вводить идентификатор? В этом корень зла :)